# Jquery does not work in Dialog angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dialog

on my index page i have a ul-tree, which i toggle with jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('label.tree-toggler').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(300);
    });
});
```

The tree is created with the following code in the html:

```
<!--  Reverse for Tree -->          
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
<label class="tree-toggler nav-header{{data.GUID_ROOT_NAME}}</label>                                    
<ul class="nav nav-list tree none">
<li data-ngdblclick="clickProfile(profile.MERKMAL)" data-ng-repeat="profile in data.ET_SELECTION_ID"><a href="" >{{profile.GUID_ROOT_NAME}}</a></li>
<li ng-repeat="data in data.tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
</script>
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li data-ng-show="data.GUID_ROOT_NAME" data-ng-repeat="data in ProfileTree"
data-ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

i want to create a dialog, where i can add the structure of the tree. but when i load the dialog, the jquery does not work anymore. in the index site, the jquery works perfect, but in the dialog it does not work.. could you help me? 
dialog:

```
$scope.opts = {
                        backdrop : true,
                        keyboard : true,
                        backdropClick : true,
                        resolve : {
                            figure : function() {
                                return angular.copy();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    var d = $dialog.dialog($scope.opts);
                    d.open('partials/dialogs/DialogAssignProfile.html',
                            'AssignProfileCtrl').then(function(result) {

                        if (result) {
                            // TODO
                        }
                    });
```

thanks!

Comment: "does not work" is not a sufficient description of your problem and could be any number of things. Is there some error message in your browser or browser console?

Comment: hi, no. as i write, the click event works for the ul in the index.html but it does not work in the dialog. maybe the it is not in the dom? im a angularjs newbie..